# Getting empty array in nodejs awaited database query

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

I want to count the user requests for each item of my jobs. I get empty array (requestArray) in my project.

I am using the following codes. How may I push the requestArray in order to return the result after each job has been counted.

```
  static getMyJobs = async (req , res , next)=>{
       const {userId}= req;
       const requestArray = [];
        try {
            const page = +req.params.p || 1;
            const limit = +req.params.l || 10;
    
            const options = paginateOptions(page, limit , { createdOn: -1 },  { path: 'user', select: 'company' });
            
            let result = await job.paginate({user: userId}, options);
   
            result.items.forEach( async j => {
              let countRequests =  await request.count({job: j._id});
              
              requestArray.push(countRequests);
            }); 
           
            result = {...result , requestArray};

            return res.status(200).json(result);

          } catch (err) {
             next(err);
          }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Replace the `forEach` loop with a `for..of` loop. Or if you want to call `.count()` on all entries asap, then use `Promise.all` and pass the result of a `.map()` call as argument. See above reference.

Comment: `forEach` doesn't await the callback.